# "Decomposition" of a connection on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Consider a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ which has some arbitrary connection specified on it. In general, such a connection could have both curvature and torsion, and the connection need not be compatible with the specified Riemmanian metric $g$ either.

My question is: Is there a "canonical" way to decompose such a connection into simpler pieces? For instance (this might be naive), would it be sensible to seek a decomposition into a sum of three terms which are Levi-Civita (i.e. torsion-free and metric compatible), metric-compatible with torsion, and a third piece which is neither?

Would such a decomposition be unique if it exists? I know the Levi-Civita connection is unique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint, any affine connection $\nabla$ can be written as$$\nabla_XY=\nabla^{LC}_XY+A(X,Y)$$where $\nabla^{LC}$ is the Levy-Civita connection and $A$ is a $(1,2)$ tensor.